# Need to select specific element using XPath in Selenium Webdriver using Java

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a problem that I just can't find the answer to.  I'm usually good in selecting specific elements in this spaghetti digit code.  This time I'm stumped.  Here is the code...

```
<div id="widget_dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_dropdown" class="dijitPopup dijitCalendarPopup" style="visibility: visible; top: 179.55px; z-index: 1000; left: 217.9px; right: auto; display: none;" role="presentation" dijitpopupparent="dijit_form_DateTextBox_0">
    <table id="dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_popup" class="dijitCalendarContainer dijitCalendar" lang="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_popup_year" dojoattachevent="onkeypress: _onKeyPress" role="grid" style="-moz-user-select: none; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 259px; visibility: visible;" dir="" widgetid="dijit_form_DateTextBox_0_popup">
        <thead>
            <tbody class="dijitReset dijitCalendarBodyContainer" dojoattachevent="onclick: _onDayClick, onmouseover: _onDayMouseOver, onmouseout: _onDayMouseOut, onmousedown: _onDayMouseDown, onmouseup: _onDayMouseUp">
                <tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row">
                <tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row">
                <tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row">
                <tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row">
                    <td class="dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" dijitdatevalue="1463904000000">
                    <td class="dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" dijitdatevalue="1463990400000">
                    <td class="dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" dijitdatevalue="1464076800000">
                    <td class="dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" dijitdatevalue="1464163200000">
                    <td class="dijitCalendarSelectedDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" dijitdatevalue="1464249600000" tabindex="0">
                    <td class="dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" dijitdatevalue="1464336000000">
                        <span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel">27</span>
                    </td>
...
...                 
<div id="widget_dijit_form_DateTextBox_1_dropdown" class="dijitPopup dijitCalendarPopup" style="visibility: visible; top: 225px; z-index: 1000; left: 217.9px; right: auto;" role="presentation" dijitpopupparent="dijit_form_DateTextBox_1">
    <table id="dijit_form_DateTextBox_1_popup" class="dijitCalendarContainer dijitCalendar dijitCalendarHover dijitHover dijitCalendarFocused dijitCalendarHoverFocused dijitHoverFocused dijitFocused" lang="" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" aria-labelledby="dijit_form_DateTextBox_1_popup_year" dojoattachevent="onkeypress: _onKeyPress" role="grid" style="-moz-user-select: none; top: 0px; overflow: hidden; width: 255px; visibility: visible;" dir="" widgetid="dijit_form_DateTextBox_1_popup">
        <thead>
            <tbody class="dijitReset dijitCalendarBodyContainer" dojoattachevent="onclick: _onDayClick, onmouseover: _onDayMouseOver, onmouseout: _onDayMouseOut, onmousedown: _onDayMouseDown, onmouseup: _onDayMouseUp">
                <tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row">
                <tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row">
                <tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row">
                <tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row">
                <tr class="dijitReset dijitCalendarWeekTemplate" role="row">
                    <td class="dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" dijitdatevalue="1432454400000">
                    <td class="dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" dijitdatevalue="1432540800000">
                    <td class="dijitCalendarCurrentDate dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate" role="gridcell" dijitdatevalue="1432627200000" tabindex="0">
                    <td class="dijitCalendarCurrentMonth dijitCalendarDateTemplate dijitCalendarHoveredDate" role="gridcell" dijitdatevalue="1432713600000">
                        <span class="dijitCalendarDateLabel">27</span>
                    </td>
```

I am trying to select the second "27".  If I use this xpath statement

```
//*[contains(@class, 'dijitCalendarCurrentMonth')][contains(., '27')]
```

It returns both elements.  So, I need to only select the one that is under

```
id="dijit_form_DateTextBox_1_popup"
```

I've tried the following...  All return no matching nodes...

```
//*[@id='dijit_form_DateTextBox_1_popup' and contains(@class, 'dijitCalendarCurrentMonth') and contains(., '27')]
//*[@id='dijit_form_DateTextBox_1_popup'][contains(@class, 'dijitCalendarCurrentMonth')][contains(., '27')]
//*[@id='dijit_form_DateTextBox_1_popup'][contains(@class, 'dijitCalendarCurrentMonth') and contains(., '27')]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `[@id='dijit_form_DateTextBox_1_popup']` you are looking for the text **27** in `table` tag itself which does not contain the text `27`. If you remove that it should find the `td` that contains the `span` containing text **27**. And, since the `td` does not have any `id` attribute with `[@id='dijit_form_DateTextBox_1_popup']` it does not find any match either.
Try

```
//table[@id='dijit_form_DateTextBox_1_popup']//span[contains(.,'27')]
```

I am also seeing the the `span` containing the text **27** is the only `span` in that table. For better performance, I think you should try the following css instead.

```
#dijit_form_DateTextBox_1_popup span
```